# Dart JSON array parsing

Tags: dart

I am trying to parse json, but can`t figure out the right way to do it.
The error appears:
TypeError: Instance of 'JSArray': type 'JSArray' is not a subtype of type 'Map'
I would appreciate if someone point me in right direction how to properly parse it.

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:async';

void main() {

loadQuote();

}

class Quote {
  final List text;
  final String author;
  final List tags;

  Quote({this.text, this.author, this.tags});

  factory Quote.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Quote(
      text: json['text'],
      author: json['author'],
      tags: json['tags'],
    );
  }
}


Future loadQuote() async {
    String jsonString = await jsonStr;
  final jsonResponse = json.decode(jsonString);
  Quote quote = Quote.fromJson(jsonResponse);
  print('Quote: ${quote.text}');
  print('Author: ${quote.author}');
}

var jsonStr = """
[
{
    "text": [
        "“Be yourself; everyone else is already taken.”"
    ],
    "author": "Oscar Wilde",
    "tags": [
        "attributed-no-source",
        "be-yourself",
        "honesty",
        "inspirational",
        "misattributed-oscar-wilde"
    ]
},
{
    "text": [
        "“So many books, so little time.”"
    ],
    "author": "Frank Zappa",
    "tags": [
        "books",
        "humor"
    ]
}
]
""";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an array of quotes. So to parse a single quote you have to do something like this:

```
Quote quote = Quote.fromJson(jsonResponse[0]); // parse first quote
```

Comment: @Kate quote text is also array, so in this case `quote.text[0]` or `quote.text.first`